# How to get the data to whom i send an email in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to display a list of emails to whom i send an email from my app.
(i am not taking the email conatcts from my iphone). 
i want the entered emails in the "To" address.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer this [Blog](http://jomnius.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-find-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller.html). The blog explains how to get recipients Email Addresses list form `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Hope it helps you.